# Lagging over a grouped time series

Tags: r, regression, time-series, lags

I have a few tens of thousands of observations that are in a time series but grouped by locations. For example:

```
location date     observationA observationB
---------------------------------------
 A       1-2010   22           12
 A       2-2010   26           15
 A       3-2010   45           16
 A       4-2010   46           27
 B       1-2010   167          48
 B       2-2010   134          56
 B       3-2010   201          53
 B       4-2010   207          42
```

I want to see if month *x*'s `observationA` has any linear relationship with month *x*+1's `observationB`.

I did some research and found a `zoo` function, but it doesn't appear to have a way to limit the lag by group. So if I used zoo and lagged `observationB` by 1 row, I'd end up with the location A's last `observationB` as location B's first `observationB`. I'd rather have the first `observationB` of any location to be `NA` or some other obvious value to indicate "don't touch this row".

I guess what I'm getting at is whether there's a built-in way of doing this in R? If not, I imagine I can get this done with a standard loop construct. Or do I even need to manipulate the data?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are several ways how you can get a lagged variable within a group. First of all you should sort the data, so that in each group the time is sorted accordingly.

First let us create a sample data.frame:

```
> set.seed(13)
> dt <- data.frame(location = rep(letters[1:2], each = 4), time = rep(1:4, 2), var = rnorm(8))
> dt
  location time        var
1        a    1  0.5543269
2        a    2 -0.2802719
3        a    3  1.7751634
4        a    4  0.1873201
5        b    1  1.1425261
6        b    2  0.4155261
7        b    3  1.2295066
8        b    4  0.2366797
```

Define our lag function:

```
 lg <- function(x)c(NA, x[1:(length(x)-1)])
```

1. Then the lag of variable within group can be calculated using `tapply`:

   ```
    > unlist(tapply(dt$var, dt$location, lg))
       a1         a2         a3         a4         b1         b2         b3         b4 
       NA  0.5543269 -0.2802719  1.7751634         NA  1.1425261  0.4155261  1.2295066
   ```
2. Using `ddply` from package **plyr**:

   ```
   > ddply(dt, ~location, transform, lvar = lg(var))
     location time        var       lvar
   1        a    1 -0.1307015         NA
   2        a    2 -0.6365957 -0.1307015
   3        a    3 -0.6417577 -0.6365957
   4        a    4 -1.5191950 -0.6417577
   5        b    1 -1.6281638         NA
   6        b    2  0.8748671 -1.6281638
   7        b    3 -1.3343222  0.8748671
   8        b    4  1.5431753 -1.3343222
   ```
3. Speedier version using `data.table` from package **data.table**

   ```
    > ddt <- data.table(dt)
    > ddt[,lvar := lg(var), by = c("location")]
        location time        var       lvar
   [1,]        a    1 -0.1307015         NA
   [2,]        a    2 -0.6365957 -0.1307015
   [3,]        a    3 -0.6417577 -0.6365957
   [4,]        a    4 -1.5191950 -0.6417577
   [5,]        b    1 -1.6281638         NA
   [6,]        b    2  0.8748671 -1.6281638
   [7,]        b    3 -1.3343222  0.8748671
   [8,]        b    4  1.5431753 -1.3343222
   ```
4. Using `lag` function from package **plm**

   ```
    > pdt <- pdata.frame(dt)
    > lag(pdt$var)
      a-1        a-2        a-3        a-4        b-1        b-2        b-3        b-4 
       NA  0.5543269 -0.2802719  1.7751634         NA  1.1425261  0.4155261  1.2295066
   ```
5. Using `lag` function from package **dplyr**

   ```
   > dt %>% group_by(location) %>% mutate(lvar = lag(var))        
   Source: local data frame [8 x 4]
   Groups: location        
     location time        var       lvar
   1        a    1  0.5543269         NA
   2        a    2 -0.2802719  0.5543269
   3        a    3  1.7751634 -0.2802719
   4        a    4  0.1873201  1.7751634
   5        b    1  1.1425261         NA
   6        b    2  0.4155261  1.1425261
   7        b    3  1.2295066  0.4155261
   8        b    4  0.2366797  1.2295066
   ```

Last two approaches require conversion from `data.frame` to another object, although then you do not need to worry about sorting. My personal preference is the last one, which was not available when writing the answer initially.

**Update:** Changed the data.table code to reflect the developments of the data.table package, pointed out by @Hibernating.

**Update 2:** Added **dplyr** example.

Comment: Great explanation! Is there a package/function that can deal with irregularly spaced grouped time series (panels) and unbalanced panels?

Comment: All of the code examples would work for unbalanced panels. For irregularly spaced time series the concept of lag is a bit complicated, since it may not exist for all groups.

Comment: You can ask about lags for irregular time series in stackoverflow. These types of questions are now off-topic in stats.SE.

Answer (score 2):

@ mpiktas   Just to briefly mention two  small oversights in version 3 of your answer. Firstly, the phrase "speedier version" has clearly been left in by error. Secondly, the word ":=" has been missed out in the code. Fixing the latter fixes the former :=)

```
library(data.table);ddt <- data.table(dt)
f0<-function() plyr::ddply(dt,~location,transform,lvar=lg(var))
f1<-function() ddt[,transform(.SD,lvar=lg(var)),by=c("location")]
f2<-function() ddt[,lvar:=lg(var),by=location]
r0<-f0();r1<-f1();r2<-f2();all.equal(r0,r1,r2,check.attributes = FALSE)
boxplot(microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f0(),f1(),f2(),times=1000L))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rather than going through all the `tapply` and additional steps, here's a faster way:

```
dt<-data.frame(location=rep(letters[1:2],each=4),time=rep(1:4,2),var=rnorm(8))
lg<-function(x)c(NA,x[1:(length(x)-1)])
dt$lg <- ave(dt$var, dt$location, FUN=lg)
```

Answer (score 2):

With dplyr

```
dt %>% group_by(location) %>% mutate(lvar=lag(var))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide a brief update: The new fastest way to do this in R is with the function `flag`/`L` in the collapse package. collapse also supports sequences of lags/leads on vectors, matrices and data frames.

```
library(collapse)
dt <- data.frame(location = rep(letters[1:2], each = 4), time = rep(1:4, 2), var = rnorm(8))
# Fastest way to append data.frame with lagged variable
settransform(dt, lvar = flag(var, 1, location, time))
dt
location time        var       lvar
1        a    1 -0.5808824         NA
2        a    2 -0.1606213 -0.5808824
3        a    3  0.6499493 -0.1606213
4        a    4 -0.2126608  0.6499493
5        b    1 -0.5082747         NA
6        b    2 -0.7450488 -0.5082747
7        b    3 -1.5895110 -0.7450488
8        b    4  0.2482062 -1.5895110

# Using plm classes - supported by collapse
pdt <- plm::pdata.frame(dt)
flag(pdt$var)
a-1        a-2        a-3        a-4        b-1        b-2        b-3        b-4 
NA -0.5808824 -0.1606213  0.6499493         NA -0.5082747 -0.7450488 -1.5895110 

# Using lag operator directly
L(dt, 1, var ~ location, ~ time)
location time     L1.var
1        a    1         NA
2        a    2 -0.5808824
3        a    3 -0.1606213
4        a    4  0.6499493
5        b    1         NA
6        b    2 -0.5082747
7        b    3 -0.7450488
8        b    4 -1.5895110

# Benchmark
library(data.table); ddt <- data.table(dt)
f2 <- function() ddt[, lvar:=shift(var), by=location]
f3 <- function() settransform(dt, lvar = flag(var, 1, location, time))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(data.table = f2(), collapse = f3(), times=1000L)

Unit: microseconds
       expr     min      lq     mean  median       uq       max neval cld
 data.table 518.539 568.519 788.7076 638.579 779.5935 23060.711  1000   b
   collapse  44.179  60.913 100.3122  78.094 104.1990  2941.214  1000  a
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the `vars` package. Sounds like a [Vector Autoregression (VAR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression) is what you may be trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

With DataCombine:

```
library(DataCombine)
slide(df, Var="observationB", TimeVar="date", GroupVar="location", NewVar="lead.observationB", 
slideBy = 1, keepInvalid = FALSE, reminder = FALSE)
```

Data  needs to be sorted as well. Use `slideBy=-1` instead for lags.